# Cannot open UIManagedDocument for editing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a question regarding CoreData with context derived from a UIManagedDocument.

In this snippet below it never logs "Error opening the document" but always "Document is still closed" - why can't I open the Document? Any ideas please?

```
-(void)openDocument
{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory     inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Date Database"];

    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]])
    {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            if (!success) {
            // Handle the error.
            NSLog(@"Error opening the document");
           }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        if (!success) {
            // Handle the error.
            NSLog(@"Error saving the file");
            }
        }];
    }

    self.theDocument = document;


    if (self.theDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed)
    {
        NSLog(@"Document still closed!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`openWithCompletionHandler` is an *asynchronous* method. It starts only a background thread to open and read the document. When you check the `documentState`, this background thread probably has not yet finished, therefore the state is still "closed".

`openWithCompletionHandler` executes the completionHandler block when the document has been opened (or when it failed).

Comment: This. I've spent way too much time on the same thing, it just takes a (surprisingly) long time for the OS to open a file.

Comment: @John67: Did my answer help? Then it would be nice if you could "accept" the answer.